# Is Iranian rial going to get boosted?

Tags: monetary-policy, money-supply, money, political-economy

I was reading about the Iran's economy and [Iranian rial](http://www.currencyliquidator.com/buy-iranian-rial). I have read the news regarding the lift of sanctions from Ira, which had allowed the purchase of Iranian rial in America.
I was having query whether the current political scenario going to help the in boosting Iranian economy?
Will the current politics will provide an economy growth to the Iran?
If any answer I would appreciate your response.

Comment: Is your question mainly about the strength of the economy of the strength of the currency? Obviously they're not unrelated, but they're also far from equivalent. Regarding the economy, I think it's fairly obvious that the lifting of economic sanctions could only be a good thing. However, low oil prices might limit some of that potential boost. With regards to the currency, it is less obvious to me what effect the lifting of sanctions might have on it.

Comment: @Shane I got your point. But I am expecting more answer.

Comment: @JafferWilson you didn't really answer his question though: Are you literally interested in the future of the Rial, or are you interested in the future strength of the economy? These are two distinct concepts, yet you mix them and ask both. Try to pin down your real (haha) variable of interest.

Comment: @FooBar I know I have mixed the question but I want the answer for both of the question: 1. the future of the Rial and 2. the future strength of the economy. That's the reason for mixing the question

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of sanctions will boost the currency because it will allow Iran to export more oil, thus encouraging other countries to buy more rials. It also is a sign of stability, which further appreciates the currency.

However, there is no way for you as an individual investor to know when this will take effect or whether it has been already priced in. So I wouldn't buy rials.

Comment: I cannot except this answer as it look like not satisfying my question fully